# programação sensor ultrassônico

Tags: expressões

Oi, eu preciso fazer programação onde eu possuo 2 sensores um de entrada e o outro de saída, quando o objeto passar pelo sensor 1 ele, o motor ira ligar, quando ele passar pelo sensor 2, o motor desligara, abaixo eu tenho parte desta programação, queria saber se tem como alguém ajudar a fazer a parte do ligar o motor e desligar o motor.

```
const int pingTrigger = 8;
const int Sensor_1 = 7;
const int Sensor_2 = 6;

void setup() {

   pinMode(pingTrigger, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(Sensor_1, INPUT);
   pinMode(Sensor_2, INPUT);
   pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
   // initialize serial communication:
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  // establish variables for duration of the ping,
  // and the distance result in inches and centimeters:
  long duration, inches, cm;
  delay(2000);
  // SENSOR 1
  // The PING))) is triggered by a HIGH pulse of 2 or more microseconds.
  // Give a short LOW pulse beforehand to ensure a clean HIGH pulse:
  digitalWrite(pingTrigger, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(pingTrigger, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(pingTrigger, LOW);

  // The same pin is used to read the signal from the PING))): a HIGH
  // pulse whose duration is the time (in microseconds) from the sending
  // of the ping to the reception of its echo off of an object.
  duration = pulseIn(Sensor_1, HIGH);

  // convert the time into a distance
  inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);
  cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);
  Serial.println("Sensor 1");
  Serial.print(inches);
  Serial.print("in, ");
  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.print("cm");
  Serial.println();

  if (cm < 10)
  {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  delay(1000);  
  }
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);  
  // SENSOR 2
  // The PING))) is triggered by a HIGH pulse of 2 or more microseconds.
  // Give a short LOW pulse beforehand to ensure a clean HIGH pulse:
  digitalWrite(pingTrigger, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(pingTrigger, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(pingTrigger, LOW);

  // The same pin is used to read the signal from the PING))): a HIGH
  // pulse whose duration is the time (in microseconds) from the sending
  // of the ping to the reception of its echo off of an object.
  duration = pulseIn(Sensor_2, HIGH);

  // convert the time into a distance
  inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);
  cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);
  Serial.println("Sensor 2");
  Serial.print(inches);
  Serial.print("in, ");
  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.print("cm");
  Serial.println();


  if (cm < 10)
  {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  delay(1000);  
  } 
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);  
}

long microsecondsToInches(long microseconds)
{
  // According to Parallax's datasheet for the PING))), there are
  // 73.746 microseconds per inch (i.e. sound travels at 1130 feet per
  // second).  This gives the distance travelled by the ping, outbound
  // and return, so we divide by 2 to get the distance of the obstacle.
  // See: http://www.parallax.com/dl/docs/prod/acc/28015-PING-v1.3.pdf
  return microseconds / 74 / 2;
}

long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds)
{
  // The speed of sound is 340 m/s or 29 microseconds per centimeter.
  // The ping travels out and back, so to find the distance of the
  // object we take half of the distance travelled.
  return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}
```

Comment: Precisa elaborar melhor qual a sua dificuldade e o que esse código tem a ver com o problema (se não entendeu, se não funciona como esperado, essas coisas).

Answer (score 0):

Neste trecho,

```
Serial.println("Sensor 1");
Serial.print(inches);
Serial.print("in, ");
Serial.print(cm);
Serial.print("cm");
Serial.println();

if (cm < 10)
{
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    delay(1000);  
}
digitalWrite(13, LOW);
```

Troque o `if (cm < 10)` para

```
if (cm < 10)
{
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
}
```

e tire o `digitalWrite(13, LOW);` que está logo após o `}`.

Neste trecho,

```
Serial.println("Sensor 2");
Serial.print(inches);
Serial.print("in, ");
Serial.print(cm);
Serial.print("cm");
Serial.println();

if (cm < 10)
{
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    delay(1000);  
} 
digitalWrite(13, LOW);
```

Troque o `if (cm < 10)` para

```
if (cm < 10)
{
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    delay(1000);
}
```

e tire o `digitalWrite(13, LOW);` que está logo após o `}`.

Dentro do `setup()`, certifique-se que depois que setou o modo do pino 13, ele fique em `LOW`,

```
digitalWrite(13, LOW);
```